# HAProxy redirect multiple domain

Tags: haproxy, web

I have only one public IP address, and three Web server in `LAN`. I want to redirect the traffic from `WAN` to the Web server like this, must support `SSL/TLS` traffic redirect:

```
https://www.example.com (A Record)===> 1.1.1.1(Public IP) ===> 192.168.1.1(Web 1)

https://www.example.net (A Record)===> 1.1.1.1(Public IP) ===> 192.168.1.2(Web 2)
```

Can **HAProxy** finish this job?

Comment: Why you want to use HAProxy? Easier to use nginx. Also with nginx you can terminate ssl traffic on frontend and don't load you backend with SSL.

Comment: Great deal, I will try to use Nginx.

Comment: Please my my answer as right, if it as useful.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Don't need to use `haproxy`, it not designed as http/https balancer. In our environment we use `nginx` with configured upstreams. Also you could terminate ssl on `nginx` and use simple http on backend.

Comment: Tis is exactly what haproxy was designed to do. Haproxy would work just as well, if not better than nginx.

Comment: Finally, I using Nginx to reverse the website, any more, thank you very much, I will try it test haproxy.

Answer (score 5):

You can route to different backends for multiple FQDNs as long as you have the cert/key for the sites. HA proxy needs to be able to decrypt the traffic and read the host header, unless you want to attempt it with TCP forwarding, but you lose the ability to do persistence. your certificate files should be in PEM format.

```
 frontend https--in
  bind 1.1.1.1:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs
  mode http
  option httplog
  use_backend bk_1 if { hdr_dom(host) -i www.example.com }     { dst_port 443 }
  use_backend bk_2 if { hdr_dom(host) -i apps.example.com }    { dst_port 443 }
  use_backend bk_3 if { hdr_dom(host) -i www.otherdomain.com } { dst_port 443 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 1 external IP, you will need to bind a SAN certificate to the external side that contains all of the URL's you would like to direct. Look at using ACL's to direct the traffic. As seen in https://seanmcgary.com/posts/haproxy---route-by-domain-name (not my blog). HAProxy is the perfect solution for this.